# How to connect to Azure using WinCE 2013

Tags: azure, compact-framework, mqtt, windows-embedded-compact

I want to establish a connection over mqtt protocol using tls on Windows Compact Embedded 2013 OS with azure IoTHub. My device supports .net 3.9 compact framework. Im open to both C# as well as C/C++ code. If anyone has worked on WinCE2013 to connect to azure over mqtt protocol please let me know..I have given many attempts but couldnt do so..

Comment: Please describe your "many attemps"

Comment: i have used the m2mqtt paho libraries...using which my azure connection through my laptop has been successfully established. But when i use the .Net Compact framework dll the SSL doesnt get enabled,due to which i get error.In their Github repo they have mentioned that the SSL Symbol is enabled but i think it is only enabled for .Net Framework and not Compact Framework..

Comment: @CSharpRocks Hey, is there any possible way to solve the problem. Im kind of stuck for a while. If you have any idea about how to go forward with please let me know..